# How to use a bootstrap template on wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, templates

I have a wordpress website which includes a member area to allow each user to edit his profile.
For this member area, I found these bootstrap templates that would be perfect for what I need.

http://themeforest.net/item/caplet-admin-responsive-html-theme-/6537086
http://themeforest.net/item/webarch-responsive-admin-dashboard-template/6157416

So, I wanted to know if it's possible to convert or use in some way these templates on wordpress ?
Since I already use a wordpress theme, it would be easier to include the bootstrap template as a plugin, do you think it's possible ?
I also heard of child themes features on wordpress but don't know much about it, do you know if it could be a solution ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You would have to use those templates and custom make your own theme, which is not an easy task. Themeforest has some nice themes for wordpress based on bootstrap. I would check those out instead.